# How to check new posts in a facebook group

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to make simplified application for my student group, i am stuck at an idea. Everything is done except notification for new posts in this group. I don't know how to check if there is a new post. Should I compare dates? Or check store first appearing post if its changed. There are also pinned posts, they seems to appear always on top of the page. And updated_time variable in graph-api seems to change order of posts by latest comment date. I need few ideas about this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the feed and use the `since` and `until` parameter. But afaik they only work on the created_time.

And you're right: If someone comments a post the updated_time is updated :)

To check if a post is new, you could save the post ids and compare them ... just a simple idea.